Google Drive PDF File - FileNotDownloadable and FileNotExportable
Having issues with using Google Drive API to either export or download a pdf. I've tried using both export_media() and get_media(). Both error out with a message about trying it's opposite's self. The error occurs in each function right after .next_chunk().
I've used the same credentials to obtain the file_id, so I can't imagine that being the problem. It's not good to have spaces in my file name, but that shouldn't be the issue either.
Is there something else I am missing?
def export_file(creds, file_id, mime_type, destination):

    try:
        # create drive api client
        service = build("drive", "v3", credentials=creds)

        # Request to export the file to the specified MIME type
        request = service.files().export_media(fileId=file_id, mimeType=mime_type)
        file = io.BytesIO()
        exporter = MediaIoBaseDownload(file, request)
        done = False

        while not done:
            status, done = exporter.next_chunk()

        # Write the file content to the specified destination
        with open(destination, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(file.getbuffer())

    except HttpError as error:
        print(error)

def download_file(creds, file_id, destination):

    try:

        # create drive api client
        service = build("drive", "v3", credentials=creds)

        request = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
        file = io.BytesIO()
        downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(file, request)
        done = False

        while done is False:
            status, done = downloader.next_chunk()

        with open(destination, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(file.getvalue())

    except HttpError as error:
        print(error)

file_mime_type = "application/pdf"
dst = dst_path + file_extension  # Colab Notebooks/My File 04-24-24.pdf
file_id = ...
creds = ...

export_file(creds=creds, file_id=item[1], mime_type=file_mime_type, destination=dst)

>>>
<HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/.../export?mimeType=application%2Fpdf&alt=media returned "Export only supports Docs Editors files.". Details: "[{'message': 'Export only supports Docs Editors files.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'fileNotExportable'}]">


download_file(creds=creds, file_id=item[1], destination=item[0])

>>>
<HttpError 403 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/...?alt=media returned "Only files with binary content can be downloaded. Use Export with Docs Editors files.". Details: "[{'message': 'Only files with binary content can be downloaded. Use Export with Docs Editors files.', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'fileNotDownloadable', 'location': 'alt', 'locationType': 'parameter'}]">




If the mimeType of your file of file_id is application/pdf, your function download_file works. If the mimeType of your file of file_id is Google Docs files (Documents, Spreadsheets, Slides), your function export_file works for exporting as PDF. Also, I confirmed this using your functions. So, can I ask you about the actual mimeType of file_id of your file?

I can confirm that the mime type is infact application/pdf. Because my creds work in other functions, I thought they would not be the issue, but if the function works for you, then it must be the problem. I've edited my question with an image of one of the error message links.

After some further testing, I generated an API key and added that to the ...(fieldID=file_id, mimType=mime_type, key=API_KEY). I find this a bit strange since I did set up 2 Auth which should require an API key. Seems that now my file_id is incorrect.

I'd like to close this post since it seems that my issue continues is not related to what my original question is. @Tanaike, appreciate you verifying that my function is correct!

Thank you for replying. From I can confirm that the mime type is infact application/pdf., in this case, I think that the function download_file works. About the API key, in this case, the file is required to be publicly shared. For example, if you can publicly share your sample file application/pdf that you have already confirmed your error, I can test your script using your file. How about this?

I think I ended up finding my issue. I had some additional code that I did not present here that was referencing an incorrect file_id. I apologize for the ill-post, but I do really appreciate you directing me through this.

I still think this should be closed since the question is too general.

Thank you for replying. I understand your situation. I agree with your decision.
